# python sparql query creating with user input

Tags: python, sparql, ontology

I am trying to build sparql query using python and take some data from user

this is my code :

```
@app.route('/api/v1/getCourseByCode', methods=['GET'])
def api_getCourseByCode():
    if 'courseId' in request.args:
        courseId = request.args['courseId']
    else:
        return "Error: No course id provided. Please specify an course id."

    onto = get_ontology("https://website/lumiere8.owl")
    onto.load()
    graph = onto.world.as_rdflib_graph()

    query = """PREFIX lumiere: <http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#>
            SELECT ?individual
            WHERE { ?individual a lumiere:Course ;
                    lumiere:Code ?propertyValue .
            FILTER(STR(?propertyValue) = {fname})}""".format(fname=courseId)

    print("---------------------------------------")
    print(query)

    course = list(graph.query_owlready(query))
    print(course)
    return course
```

and I got the following error :

[image]

The query is working like this :

```
course = list(graph.query_owlready("""PREFIX lumiere: <http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#>
    SELECT ?individual
    WHERE { ?individual a lumiere:Course ;
                    lumiere:Code ?propertyValue .
    FILTER(STR(?propertyValue) = "CS101")}
    """))
```

but the problem is that I want to take user input from the api method

Comment: Try `rdf:type` instead of `a`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin the error change to be KeyError: ' ?individual rdf' , the problem is not in the query itself I have tested it in protege, the problem in the python and string format

Comment: @StanislavKralin please check my edit

Answer (score 0):

This is what works with me using %s in the query

```
course=list(graph.query_owlready("""PREFIX lumiere: <http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#>
    SELECT ?individual
    WHERE { ?individual a lumiere:Course ;
                    lumiere:Code ?propertyValue .
    FILTER(STR(?propertyValue) = "%s")}
    """ %courseId))
```